# Bent pin on motherboard fixed. Will it last?

Tags: motherboard

I have recently had my motherboard fixed for bent pins (today is recently), which caused a malfunctioning ram slots, A1-A2. Lab said they can't insure the fix because bent pins fix can't be 100% good. Motherboard is Rog maximus xii extreme. Question is, once the pins are fixed and the cpu is in place, can it malfunction again? Do I have to worry if I want to change my cpu, or when I need to restart the system due to an update?
Do I have to worry for other parts of the mobo not functioning such as the dimm.2 slot or xmp configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> once the pins are fixed and the cpu is in place, can it malfunction again?

Yes, but not by itself. Pins don't bend themselves spontaneously, they only get bent by people.

> Do I have to worry if I want to change my cpu

Yes.

> or when I need to restart the system due to an update?

No, updates won't put more physical stress on them.

> Do I have to worry for other parts of the mobo not functioning such as the dimm.2 [sic!] slot or xmp configuration?

If they work, they'll keep working until you decide to swap the CPU and weakened pins happen to break.

Comment: I do not have a reason to touch the cpu once it's intact so here's for that. I only worry that I won't spontaneously get QCode 55 when restarting the pc or turning on after shut down.I don't want to worry when I move the case around as well. I do believe that by physical stress you mean changing the cpu or something of sort.

Comment: @BarrJ Yup. Under normal conditions the CPU should be fixed in place by the bracket and cooling solution. You can move the case safely.